# How many citta vithis are there in Abhidhamma?

Tags: abidhamma

I need to know;How many citta vithis are described there in *Abhidhamma* and what are they?(ie:chakkudwara citta vithi,manodwara citta vithi, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Bhavaṅga
The bhavaṅga citta, mentioned earlier, is the primary form of mind. It flows from conception to
death except when interrupted by a stimulus through one of the sense doors. When a stimulus
enters, consciousness becomes active, launching into a thought process (citta vīthi). Thought
processes have been analysed in great detail in the Abhidhamma.
A complete thought process, occurring through the physical sense doors, is made up of
seventeen thought moments (citta khaṇa). These are:
1) A bhavaṅga that flows by in a passive state when one of the five physical sense organs
comes in contact with its object (atīta bhavaṅga).
2) A bhavaṅga that vibrates for one thought moment (bhavaṅga calana).
3) A bhavaṅga that cuts off the flow (bhavaṅga upaccheda).
10
4) A citta that turns towards the object through the sense door that has been stimulated
(pañcadvāra-vajjana).
5) The appropriate sense consciousness; in the case of the eye, for example, eye
consciousness (cakkhu viññāṇa).
6) Next a thought moment—the sampaṭicchana citta—which has the function of
receiving the object.
7) When the object has been received another thought moment, called the santīraṇa citta,
arises, performing the function of investigating the object.
8) The act (kamma) itself, especially if it was a weighty one.
9–15) The object having been determined, the most important stage from an ethical
standpoint follows. This stage, called javana, consists of seven consecutive thought
moments all having an identical nature. It is at this stage that good or evil is done,
depending on whether the cittas have wholesome or unwholesome roots. Therefore,
these javana thought moments have roots and also produce new kamma.
17) Following the seventh javana the registering stage occurs, composed of two thought
moments called tadālambana. When the second registering citta has perished, the
bhavaṅga follows, flowing on until interrupted by another thought process.

http://103.242.110.22/theravadins/English-articles/abhidhamma-in-practice.pdf

Comment: Here this is a description of a citta vithi( a single citta vithi ), there are more citta vithis like this

Comment: Yes. For that, you have to read _Comprehensive Manual of Abhidhamma_

Comment: I edited your comment above, other people can't read a link to a file which exists on your local (Windows) file system.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Comprehensive Manual of Abhidhamma (page 151):

“According to the sense-doors, the six cognitive processes (*vīthi*) are:
(i) The process connected with the eye-door (*cakkhhudvāravīthi*)
(ii) The process connected with the ear-door (*sotadvāravīthi*)
(iii) The process connected with the nose-door (*ghāndadvāravīthi*)
(iv) The process connected with the tongue-door (*jivhādvāravīthi*)
(v) The process connected with the body-door (*kāyadvāravīthi*)
(vi) The process connected with the mind-door (*manodvāravīthi*)”

This is a simple answer to your question… but I am curious, why did you ask this question? Why is this important to you?

Comment: These are only dhvara citta vithis, there are more like maranasanna citta vithi etc...

Comment: Yes, you can add the absorption (jhāna) process, the attainment of cessation process (nirodhasamāpatti), the death and rebirth process, and the sainthood process. Lots of details in the book "Process of Consciousness and Matter" by Bhaddanta Dr. Rewata Dhamma that can be downloaded for free from the Pariyatti.org website.